# Heml check If nil pointer

Tags: deployment, nullpointerexception, null, kubernetes-helm

In my template to deploy an application i have the following:

```
{{- if .Values.application.rbac.enabled -}}
  serviceAccountName: service-account-cache
{{- else -}}

{{- end -}}
```

the point is that such file is used dynamically, I mean, I have several microservice that uses such files but algo when I use:

```
helm upgrade --install ${releaseName} -f ../folder/secrets/${env.appId}.yaml
```

depending on the microservive it also adds differents -f yaml file. Some of thems have

```
application:
  rbac:
    enabled: true
```

but another doesn't.

in those who don't have such additinal properties i have the following error:

```
<.Values.application.rbac.enabled>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enabled
```

because Values.application.rbac of course is not defined.

How can I do it so that additionally if it is not defined, do not do the if but no nil pointer occurs?

Thanks in advance